# Problems with Getting Started with Ionic OSX

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, xampp, ionic-framework

I have a problem when it comes starting with ionic in Mac. I'll explain the steps I have taken and errors I found, to see if anyone can help me.

I installed node.js from this site: nodejs.org

Thereupon I executed these commands:

1. `$ sudo npm install -g cordova ionic cordova`
2. `$ ionic start myApp tabs`
3. `$ ionic serve`

And with this last order I can see the application running. but if I try to do this:

```
$ sudo ionic platform add ios
```

I get this error:

[image]

But, These are the versions of the programs I use:

- cordova - 3.6.3-0.2.13
- Ionic - 1.2.7 Xcode - 6.0.1 (6A317)
- XAMPP - 1.8.3-3

Someone could help me solve my problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried that without sudo ?

Comment: and did you make sure that the installation went ok ?

Comment: Yes, I tested with and without sudo and the result is the same

Answer (score 2):

The error message says the problem, "Cordova can only run in Xcode version 4.6 or greater."

You need to install Xcode and the Xcode command line tools. Download Xcode from the AppStore, and run this command in the terminal to get the command line tools.

`xcode-select --install`

Also do not use `sudo` with the `ionic` commands. You'll possibly cause permission issues down the road.

Comment: Now everything works fine (without using sudo), but when I run this command (ionic add platform android) I get this error:

Comment: /Users/developer/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.
    at /Users/developer/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:158:19
    at _fulfilled (/Users/developer/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)...

Comment: You have to have the android sdk installed and in your path too. I use homebrew to handle this `brew install android-sdk`. Ionic is built on top of these other platforms, so you have to have them setup too.

Comment: Yes, I have the android sdk installed, but the error continuous

Comment: When you run `android list` do you see output or an error? I had problems when I was using a beta version of Xcode and OSX that certain CLI tools had to be reinstalled to get things registered again.